# Debugging Windows Form Application C# adding a watch

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm new to coding in Windows form applications (and quite new to coding in general). I'm trying to debug my code. I've always used watches while debugging however I cannot seem to add any of my variables to the watch list. Does anyone have any idea why?

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the following two variables:
1. TheUser
2. PathName

Once I figure that out I want to display the string ImageFileWrapper in the text box "ImageFileWrapperPath".

Every little bit of help is greatly appreciated. If at all possible, I would like to have explanations so that I can learn for the future.

Please see my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ChooseImageFileWrapper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String TheUser = Environment.UserName;
            String PathName = "C:\Users\" + TheUser + "\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = PathName;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Image File Wrapper Chooser";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    String ImageFileWrapper = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ImageFileWrapperPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to have a break point hit before you can add something to the watch list.

Comment: I'm not sure how your even getting to the point of debugging, because this line should be throwing a compiler error: `String PathName = "C:\Users\" + TheUser + "\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";`.  You need to either escape your back slashes, i.e. use "\\" or use verbatim strings, i.e. `@"C:\Users\" + TheUser + @"\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what problem do you have adding those variable to the watch list. Usually you set a breakpoint on the required point, run the program until you hit the breakpoint and then right click on the variable name and choose Add Watch....
By the way, being these variables, local variables, you don't need to add them to the Watch window, they are already in the Locals windows (DEBUG->WINDOW->Locals)

However your code has a simple error in this line

```
String PathName = "C:\Users\" + TheUser + "\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";
```

In C# the backslash need to be escaped doubling it or prefixing the whole string with the verbatim character like this

```
String PathName = @"C:\Users\" + TheUser + "\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";
```

Finally I suggest to avoid building manually paths string but use instead the Path.Combine method

```
String PathName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users",TheUser,@"Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\");
```

And as a last bit, you could use this code to get the user directory

```
string userdir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string  PathName = Path.Combine(userdir, @"Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\");
```

This will work also if the user changed its user folder through the OS tools.

Answer (score 0):

So I am also new to programming.  But I will try and help the best I can.  So for your

String PathName = "C:\Users\" + TheUser + "\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\";

it looks like you are have a lot of issues.

So first of all you need to \ in front of all your \'s because the code thinks that is an escape character.  Second thing I noticed is that your + TheUser + and ; are still part of the string and not concatenated.  So this is the code that I have that did not give me any errors or warnings.

String PathName = "'C:\\Users\\'" + TheUser + "'\\Dropbox\\PATENT\\Waks & Co\\'";

Now for the TheUser variable are you getting that information for a text box?

Comment: I'm sorry for that this was my first post on stack overflow.  I will try not to start with so again.